# Monitor retweets with PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I have a website Foo.com that creates a tweet for the user @FooWebsite.
Users on the website can retweet it and users directly on Twitter too.

I would like to monitor in real-time (< 10min) the retweets of all the tweets created by @FooWebsite.

For the moment, I think of using a cronjob that requests Twitter every minute to get info (number of retweets) about those tweets as I have their IDs.
Is there no subscription/callbacks like on Facebook API ?

I'm using PHP5.5 on Unix/Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count Retweets as they happen in real time, the recommended way is to use the Streaming APIs.

In particular, the [`statuses/filter`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter) endpoint and its [`follow`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters%23follow) parameter will contain Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.

In order to distinguish these Retweets from the other Tweets streamed by the endpoint, you can rely on the presence of a `retweeted_status` nested object which will embed the original Tweet, allowing you to identify and focus exclusively on Retweets and count the ones you are interested in.

Please also note a `retweet_count` attribute value is attached to that node and represents, roughly, the number of times that original Tweet has been retweeted as of some time near when you were streamed the Tweet.